# Why sorting by clikcing on columns in dataTable does not work?

Tags: jquery, datatable

in my laravel 8 app with jquery 3.4/bootstrap 4.6 I use dataTable 1.10.19
and I need to make data sortable by some columns and I set bSortable property to true for some columns
like :

```
var url = "{!! route('educationsGetFilter') !!}";


oTable = $('#tzdatatables').dataTable({
    "language": {
        "emptyTable": "No educations found"
    },
    "bServerSide": true,

    "ajax": {
        "url": url,
        "data": function ( d ) {
            d.search = $('.dataTables_filter > label > input').val();
            d.category_id = $("#filter_education_category_id").val();
            d.document_type = $("#filter_document_type").val();
            d.tags = $("#filter_tags").val();
        }
    },
    "bProcessing": true,
    "aoColumns": [{
        "bSortable": true,
        "mData": 0 // Sr No
    }, {
        "sWidth": "30%",
        "bSortable": true,
        "mData": 1 // Name
    }, {
        "bSortable": true,
        "mData": 2 // Status label
    }, {
        "mData": 3 // Education category
    }, {
        "mData": 4 // $created_at_formatted
    }, {
        "mData": 5 // $updated_at_formatted
    }, {
        "mData": null,
        "bSortable": true,
        "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
            var editurl = data[6];
            var public_url = data[7];

            return '<div>\n\
        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-icon" href="' + editurl + '" title="Edit education"><i class="fas fa-edit icon-nm"></i></a>\n\
        <a data-id="' + data[0] + '" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-icon delete_this mb-1" href="javascript:;" title="Delete education"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt icon-nm"></i></a>\n\
       <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info btn-icon ml-2" href="' + public_url + '" title="Open education on frontend"><i class="fas fa-external-link-alt icon-nm""></i></a>\n\
        </div>';
        }
    }]
```

but I see “Up”/"Down" icons with name of any columns : https://prnt.sc/1qstemm
but sorting does not work for any of columns...

What is wrong ?

Thanks!

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: Not any errors in the cosnole .
I just payed attention that in controller orderBy:
        $educations       = Education
            ::getByTitle($filter_search)
            ->getByEducationCategoryId($filter_education_category_id)
            ->getByDocumentType($filter_document_type)
            ->getByTags($filter_tags)
            ->orderBy('education.created_at', 'desc')
             ...

but I suppose sorting work on client and has nothing with orderBy ?

Comment: I think that `orderBy` is default then client can change it. Do you have any live version of that problem?

Comment: " live version" - accessiblle in net ? Not now are there some sort proporties I could miss to use?

Comment: I can't help you without see.

Comment: I uploaded this problem at our server : https://streamgeeks-rebranded-dev.cloudns.cl/stream_geeks_admin/educations
Pleaase use login tester@tester.com / 111111
Thanks in advance!

Comment: My connection block that site ^^ can you use a simple tool `[<>]` here ?

Comment: Which "simple tool" do you mean ? Why site was blocked? It must be accessible ? Are there some online tools(like fiddle I suppose) with similar sorting functionality ? Please point

Comment: [Stack Overflow & run code snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356678/stack-overflow-run-code-snippet) <-- look here, your website seems like not secure. (update SSL?)

Comment: service
https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=https://streamgeeks-rebranded-dev.cloudns.cl/
shows : streamgeeks-rebranded-dev.cloudns.cl resolves to 18.198.221.45
  
Server Type: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
  
The certificate should be trusted by all major web browsers (all the correct intermediate certificates are installed).
  
The certificate was issued by Let's Encrypt.
  
The certificate will expire in 6 days. 
  
The hostname (streamgeeks-rebranded-dev.cloudns.cl) is correctly listed in the certificate.

Please point whic problems you have(maybe with printsreen)

Comment: The security system of the network operator blocks me saying that it is "a possible malware"